# Installing UbuntuStudio from Ubuntu 22.04: how to get the same desktop as UbuntuStudio?

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

on my laptop I installed Ubuntu, then I installed UbuntuStudio using ubuntu-studio-installer.
I notice than my desktop is not quite the same as the desktop I would become if I install UbuntuStudio (without previous Ubuntu install)...
and I would like my desktop to be exactly like the UbuntuStudio (icons aligned horizontally in the top left corner etc... while on my laptop, icons are aligned vertically, I also have a "Activities" icon).

Any idea how I can get exactly the same Desktop as a genuine UbuntuStudio desktop on my laptop ?
Thanks for your help !
Vincent

Comment: The *Ubuntu Studio Installer* adds the *Ubuntu Studio* goodies to your existing desktop. As you were using Ubuntu's default GNOME desktop; you've got Ubuntu Studio *goodies* on that GNOME desktop.  The default install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS uses the KDE Plasma desktop (ie. a *reduced* Kubuntu base is used) so why not just install Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS?  as you appear to have gone the wrong way to get there (*sure you can add KDE Plasma, but your system will be more bloated than a clean install*).  What did you want to achieve?

Comment: > why not just install Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS? It just didn't work ! Well I guess I will have to install plasma then

Comment: Ubuntu Studio uses the `calamares` installer (*as does Lubuntu*), which has some *quirks* that maybe related to why you said it "*just didn't work !*", so if you ask about the Ubuntu Studio installer issues we could help there (eg. partition problems are what I've most encountered in QA-testing the `calamares` installer; those however are easily worked around; also the `calamares` found on 22.04.1 is much better than that used on 22.04 ISOs).